# Simple way of client-server communication in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I found a very useful code snippet [on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/shawncxc/80a4131701c11e1bbb7b) that can provide simple server-client communication in NodeJS.

After some minor formatting, my code looks like this:

**The client (Jade + Javascript)**

```
head
    title jsonp test
    script(src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js')
    script(type='text/javascript').

    $(function () {
        $('#select_link').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('select_link clicked');

            var data = {};
            data.title = "title";
            data.message = "message";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: 'http://localhost:7776/domaintest',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('success');
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            });
        });
    });

body
    #select_div
        a#select_link(href='#') Test
```

**The server (Javascript)**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/domaintest', function(req, res){
    var obj = {};
    console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    res.send(req.body);
});

app.listen(7776);
```

**Route defined to the client** (I was told it's unnecessary for the server as `app.post` serves the purpose)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

The result is a simple text reading "Test" that can be clickable. When I click, the actual events should happen as far as I read it out from the code, but insted browser says `POST http://localhost:7776/domaintest 404 (Not Found)` in `jquery-1.6.2.min.js:18`. To be very precise, the error occures in `$.ajax`, according to the debugger.

Since the jQuery code is practically unreadable because of the formatting (not judging, it might have its reason), I need your help. What's the possible source of the error? Did I forget mentioning something?

Comment: What happens when you **browse** to `http://localhost:7776/domaintest`? Is your app listening?

Comment: @cale_b `domaintest` is practically empty. It consists of a Jade page with some minor text, no attached JS script, and a route (excluding the render input) *completely* identical to the one I defined for the client.

Comment: When you enter `http://localhost:7776/domaintest` into your browser do you get a 404?

Comment: @KarlP.Galvez no. It works perfectly - on the other hand, as I mentioned above, it does not do anything.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt Is your entire app running on localhost? If so, try `url: '/domaintest'` you may be running into CORS issues. It's been awhile since I've done development on localhost, so I could be way off.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt you dont have any API endpoint for POST Method defined anywhere. That is the reason its throwing 404. Remove content type header and change POST to GET, it might work.

Comment: @KarlP.Galvez nothing has changed.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt are you sure the server is running? I noticed `var app = express.createServer();` which is deprecated. Have you tried `var app = express();`?

Comment: @prashanth it solved the problem, however what is defined in the Jade file (the `console.log` scripts) is not executed. Are you sure it's a proper way?

Comment: @KarlP.Galvez I replaced `express.createServer();` to `express()`, but nothing has changed.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt Yes, if you just want to get the HTML content. And NO if you want your server to do something else. Then you have to define API endpoints for POST.

Comment: @prashanth I want the latter to do. Can you explain how to do that in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and outside help, I've found the solution.

For `domaintest`, there was a route defined, which is almost identical to the one I defined for the client. Well, to the `domaintest` route, I had to add the next function call, right after `router.get`:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({data: 'asd'}));
});
```

The so-called server code above is practically unused and unnecessary; `domaintest` serves as a server.

Answer (score 2):

Change your server.js file to this. I havent tested the code but this should work.

```
    var express = require('express');
        var app = express.createServer();
        var router = express.Router();

        app.use(express.bodyParser());


    router.post('/domaintest', function(req, res, next) {
      var obj = {};
            console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
            res.send(req.body);
    });

app.listen(7776);
```

You can read this for more information http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2014/10/01/creating-a-restful-api-tutorial-with-nodejs-and-mongodb/

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt Any error? Are you able to debug it?

Comment: `jquery-1.6.2.min.js:18 POST http://localhost:7776/domaintest 404 (Not Found)` according to Opera Dragonfly.

Comment: The complete flow: `send @ jquery-1.6.2.min.js:18 ->
f.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.6.2.min.js:18 ->
(anonymous function) @ index:9 ->
f.event.handle @ jquery-1.6.2.min.js:17 ->
i.handle.k @ jquery-1.6.2.min.js:16
`

Comment: To be more specific, `index:9` is where `$.ajax` is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your calling `body-parser` incorrectly. Body parser isn't part of express so you can't do `express.bodyParser`.

You need to include it like so:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

Comment: That's possibly and likely true, but according to Opera Dragonfly, it doesn't even reach that part of the code. 
`jquery-1.6.2.min.js:18 POST http://localhost:7776/domaintest 404 (Not Found)`