# How to pass object from one file to another in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I have node js server file (index.js) and client file (orderlist.js)
In index.js i am getting promise object , like that

```
function returnOrderArray() {
    var i = 0;
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM orders', function(error, results) {
            while (i < results.length) {

                order.id[i] = results[i].id;
                order.wavetype[i] = results[i].wavetype;
                order.color[i] = results[i].color;
                order.thick[i] = results[i].thick;
                order.readydate[i] = results[i].readydate;
                order.createdate[i] = results[i].createdate;
                order.manager[i] = results[i].manager;

                i++;
            }
            resolve(order);
            // console.log(order);


        });
    });
    return promise;
}
```

then i want to pass it to other js file.
I tried to do that with module.exports

```
app.get('/orderlist', checkUserSession, async function(request, response) {
    returnOrderArray().catch(error => console.log(error)).then((() => {
        module.exports.order = order;
        response.render("orderlist.ejs", { username: request.session.username });
    })).catch(error => console.log(error));
});
```

and then import it in orderlist.js

```
var ind = require('../../index')


function asd() {
    alert(ind.order);
}
```

but it seems not to work.

**What am i doing wrong , and what's the best way to pass objects to other files in js?**

oh , and file architecture

[filearch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZdsx.png)

Comment: If one file is used in the server and the other file is used in the user client, how can you expect them to import each other? They can only communicate over the network, using HTTP requests or more advanced solution such as websockets

Comment: See something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213706/simple-way-of-client-server-communication-in-nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `export` your module like so: `module.exports = returnOrderArray`

try this,

orderlist.js

```
const returnOrderArray = () => {...some code..}
module.exports = returnOrderArray
```

index.js

```
const returnOrderArray = require('./path/to/orderlist.js')

const run = async() => {
const orderlist = await returnOrderArray() // use await or then as you prefer
}
run()
```

[async_await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) link if curious!

Hope this will work :)